# How to output name of a resource from module in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have been trying to figure out how to output the "name" parameter of a resource in Terraform so I can then use this in other modules. This is my best attempt so far:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_infrastructure" {
  name     = "rg_${var.environment}_Infrastructure"
  location = var.location
}

output "rg_infrastructureName" {
    value = module.rg_infrastructure.name # <- How to get value of "name" from above resource group into here.
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of this. I can offcourse make it work if I write `"rg_${var.environment}_Infrastructure"` twice, but the whole point is I dont want to as then there is a chance of a missmatch.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inside a module's code, you don't reference values via `module.whatever` you just reference the values directly. Your `output` should be:

```
output "rg_infrastructureName" {
    value = azurerm_resource_group.rg_infrastructure.name 
}
```

---

Now, **outside** your module, you would declare your module and then access the module's output values like this:

```
module "module_name" {
  source = "./module_source"

  # Other module attributes
}

resource "some_other_resource" "resource_name" {
  infraName = module.module_name.rg_infrastructureName
}
```

Note that the output is referenced as `module.module_name.rg_infrastructureName` where `module_name` is whatever you named the module when you declared it.

Comment: The last part I managed to test my way to but the internal part where I first reference it by resource type was not intuitive to me at first.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
output "rg_infrastructureName" {
    value = azurerm_resource_group.rg_infrastructure.name
}
```

Needs to start with resource type, then its name, and then the value you want from it.